# Collapsible accordion in form-list?

Tags: accordion, moqui

I have successfully implemented a collapsible accordion on fields inside a form-single tag, however I am unable to do so on fields in a form-list tag. The "Making Apps with Moqui" documentation covers accordion implementation only within form-single, so i checked the xml-form-2.0.xsd file and nowhere does it say that field-accordion (and by extension field-group, field-layout). Is it possible to have a collapsible form-list, or is it indeed only reserved for single forms? I should also add that my form-list resides inside a container tag.